# Multiple resources in one service

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

In my MEAN application, I have a product model like this :

```
product: {
        field: //some string value//, 
        reviews: //an array of review objects// 
        }
```

Now I am going to apply different restrictions for saving `field` and `reviews`, so my API endpoints will be like this :

```
/* specific route for updating reviews */
router.put('/products/reviews/:id', checkRightsToUpdateReviews, updateProductReviews);

/* specific route for updating field */
router.put('/products/:id', checkRightsToUpdateField, updateProductField);
```

Those endpoints are reached by my Angular service `productData`, respectively via methods `productData.updateReview(product)` and `productData.updateField(product)`.

Thus in my `productData` service, I'm using two resources :

One with url `/products/reviews/:id` for the `updateReview` method, and one with url `/products/:id` for the `updateField` method.

**I feel like I'm not doing the separation of concerns properly.**

The problem originates from the fact that my model has fields that have to be treated differently. But it makes sense to me to have all the CRUD operations for `products` in one service.

What would be an obviously more elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use one authorization middleware to check for both cases.

```
router.put('/products/:id', checkUpdateRights, updateProduct);

function checkUpdateRights(req, res, next){
    if(req.body.reviews && !hasReviewRights(req)){ // check only if reviews exists in body
        res.status(401).send({ error: "Unauthorized to update product reviews" });
    }
    if(!hasUpdateRights(req)){ // for other fields
        res.status(401).send({ error: "Unauthorized to update product" });
    }
    else{
        return next();
    }
};

function hasReviewRights(req){
    // return true or false
};

function hasUpdateRights(req){
    // return true or false
};
```